# Creating Modal Component with Separate Modal Trigger Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I'm new to React so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a modal component that will be triggered from a onClick() function from any global element i.e: link, button, span or whatever throughout the whole app.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const display = {
  display: 'block'
};

const hide = {
  display: 'none'
};


class Modal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        toggle: false
      }
    }

    toggle(event) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        toggle: !prevState.toggle
      }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.toggle}>Show Modal</button>
            <div className="modal" style={this.state.toggle ? display : hide} >
              <div className="modal-content">
                {this.props.children}
                <button onClick={this.toggle}>Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

}


module.exports = Modal;
```

Comment: This would be really tedious without some sort of state management library like Redux or MobX. Take a look at those.

Comment: How about using `react-bootstrap-modal`? I can show you an example if it's OK

Comment: Sure, I'm open to more ideas

Comment: Just added an answer, please try it and tell me if there's any errors on your console, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-bootstrap-modal`:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap-modal
```

Then in your component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap-modal';

export default class ModalExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  openModal = () => this.setState({ open: true })

  closeModal = () => this.setState({ open: false })

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.openModal}>Launch modal</button>

        <Modal
          show={this.state.open}
          onHide={this.closeModal}
          aria-labelledby="ModalHeader"
        >
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title id='ModalHeader'>A Title Goes here</Modal.Title>
            <div onClick={this.closeModal}>CLOSE HERE</div>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <p>Some Content here</p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            // If you don't have anything fancy to do you can use
            // the convenient `Dismiss` component, it will
            // trigger `onHide` when clicked
            <Modal.Dismiss className='btn btn-default'>Cancel</Modal.Dismiss>

            // Or you can create your own dismiss buttons
            <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.closeModal}>
              CLOSE HERE TOO
            </button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For further reference, please go here:

https://github.com/jquense/react-bootstrap-modal

You may also need to include bootstrap-CSS file if necessary! Please post here some errors if any, thanks